# Intellij, open up superclass, or give a list of superclasses anywhere in a class

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-14

Intellij, open up superclass, or give a list of superclasses anywhere in a class.

How?

Annoying that you have to navigate all the way up to the class, place the cursor at the class and CTRL + B.

Anywhere in a class I want to jump/open the superclass, if several ( not Object ) then show me a quick list so I can choose then hit enter.

There are a few ways that "this kind of works" but they all suck.

Navigate to super method works only if there is a method in the super class that matches. So don't give me that tip.

Same thing goes navigating to sub classes. There you should be able to jump to a declaration by first getting a list but right now you also have to be positioned in a correct place, like a method, class or interface. That is annoying as well.

Type declaration is possibly one, although I'd prefer a quick dialog box for this, and you can't use Enter to open a file.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl + U` (open super method) *outside* any method. This will open the super class instead. I don't know any way to open the super class within a method with a single shortcut.

Comment: It would be nice to get a list of those superclasses wherever you are, but this might have to do, although the inconsistency of it makes likely not be used. Annoying that you will sometimes have to move out of a method to get to your location. Inside an overriden method you might jump two or more superclasses up depending on where it is encountered first in the super chain. Thanks though, you've been great today :)